# Visual Studio Setup offers development settings of Web Development and Web Development (code only). Whats the difference?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I installed Visual Studio 2017 during the setup it offered development settings Web Development and Web Development (code only). Whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only makes a difference for WebForms development.  The main difference is that the Code Only profile will hide the WebForms designer by default.  If you're using more other web technologies like MVC you won't really notice any difference.

When this was originally introduced many years ago, it would also hide additional toolbars, but VS has since cleaned that up for all profiles.  I can't remember if it still hides extra tool windows or not.